# Why doesn't the new FreeAndNil use a typed var parameter?

Tags: delphi, memory-management

Here's the new FreeAndNil implementation in 10.4 Sydney (with the now redundant ARC code stripped out)

```
procedure FreeAndNil(const [ref] Obj: TObject);
var
  Temp: TObject;
begin
  Temp := Obj;
  TObject(Pointer(@Obj)^) := nil;
  Temp.Free;
end;
```

I understand this is now type safe while the 10.3 and older versions weren't but why not implement the new version as

```
procedure PossiblyVeryBadButWhyExactly_FreeAndNil(var Obj : TObject);
var
  Temp: TObject;
begin
  Temp := Obj;
  Obj := nil;
  Temp.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

A colleague pointed out the problem with my implementation. When you actually try and use it with a TObject descendant you get the compiler error

> [dcc32 Error] Project3.dpr(20): E2033 Types of actual and formal var
>   parameters must be identical

I'd seen that error before but it's not one you come across very often. That's my excuse anyway.

Comment: The point of E2033 is to ensure type safety - unlike `FreeAndNil` which does just write nil into the passed variable `var` can be assigned a new value to. If you pass a variable of a subtype of `TObject` lets say `TFruit` that type information is lost inside the routine and you can just fine assign an instance of `TAnimal` to it - but that clearly violates the type safety because now you have a `TAnimal` instance in your `TFruit` variable.

Comment: @StefanGlienke "*The point of E2033 is to ensure type safety - unlike `FreeAndNil`*" - lack of type safety is true with the old pre-10.4 untyped var version of `FreeAndNil`, but is not true anymore with the new 10.4 const-ref-type version of `FreeAndNil`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know that - the comment was to explain why E2033 occurs at all for typed var parameters.